# How to integrate Vue3 via WebPack (or Mix or Vite) to Yii2 Advanced correctly - where it can be placed - in root or frontend and backend each folders?

Tags: webpack, yii2, vuejs3

I need Vue3 in my Yii2 Advanced project, in Front and Back booth.

Now I have some integration via CDN, but I need more functionality, then I need Vue3 via WebPack(?)

Where can I placed WebPack and folder with Vue sources?

Two separates installations in @frontend and @backend folders, or one in the root?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's best approach but I usually have Vue app as independent project. Then I integrate built bundle into the Yii app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends(of course) what kind of application is that, but I would go for separate bundles. My way to handle it is to think about them as separate projects.

I prefer to use Vite.js, so you can put vite.config.js in frontend folder and backend, and then you can place your assets (vue sources) in frontend folder and backend folder.

Other approach is to have have bundler config and and assets folder in root, but it requires more advanced bundler config.

Here is some links for reference:

[Article about how implement Vite, Vue in PHP](https://medium.com/@witkowski.bartlomiej1/php-with-vite-and-vue-simple-implementation-1c90af6f5b9e)

[Repository with example integration Vite, Vue and PHP](https://github.com/bar-tech-dev/php-vite)